# what is the difference between amazon edge location and cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

How Amazon edgelocation and cloudfront relate to each other?
I understand Both are used for reducing the latency and keep information (cache info)at the nearest location.

Answer (score 4):

CloudFront is made up of many edge locations. Each edge location is an Amazon datacenter (or colocation facility that has Amazon equipment somewhere in it), spread out all over the world for low latency. A request to a CloudFront endpoint goes to one of the edge locations closest to your current physical location.

You can see the full list/map here: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/details/

[image]